# How to add an axis to an image (using ImageJ or any other software)?

Tags: images, image-editing, imagej

I am looking for a fast method to add an x and y axis to the outline of an image, as in the example below:

[image: Example picture]

That particular image was done in [13 lines in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38632/image-with-axis) in a rather complicated fashion. Is there a faster way to do this with ImageJ (hours of googling yielded absolutely nothing) or any other software?

Comment: gnuplot can do it in a few easy lines, will do if I find time and there's still interest.